# flowtype not complaining about missing React prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, flowtype

I have the following Counter example:

```
/**
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { increment, decrement } from '../actions/counter'
import type { State } from '../store'

type Props = {
  counter: number,
  increment: Function,
  decrement: Function,
  hello: Function // There is no `hello` prop coming in to the component, but there doesn't seem to be an error
}

class Counter extends Component<*, Props, *> {
  props: Props

  render() {
    const { counter, increment, decrement } = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{counter}</h1>
        <button onClick={decrement}>-</button>
        <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: State) {
  return {
    counter: state.counter
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Function) {
  return {
    increment: () => dispatch(increment()),
    decrement: () => dispatch(decrement())
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter)
```

I have a required `hello` prop field in my `Props` type, however I don't seem to be getting any errors even though the component is not receiving a `hello` prop. Why is this happening?

Comment: How the `Counter` component is used?

Comment: @zerkms It's just rendered in my `App` component by doing `<Counter />`. The

Comment: Do you have /* @flow */ at the top of your files?

Comment: Yeah, I do – I'll edit my post to reflect that. Flow is definitely running on the file, for example if I try accessing something that isn't actually on `this.props`, I'll get an error. I'm just wondering why it's not complaining about the `Counter` component not receiving the `hello` prop.

Answer (score 0):

This is showing the error of the missing properties.
I changed `<*, Props, *>` to `<void, Props, void>`.
And export the Counter class without Redux.

```js
 // @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { increment, decrement } from '../actions/counter'
import type { State } from '../store'

type Props = {
  counter: number,
  increment: Function,
  decrement: Function,
  hello: Function // There is no `hello` prop coming in to the component, but there doesn't seem to be an error
}

// added export for Counter and void instead of *
export class Counter extends Component<void, Props, void> {
  props: Props;

  render() {
    const { counter, increment, decrement } = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{counter}</h1>
        <button onClick={decrement}>-</button>
        <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: State) {
  return {
    counter: state.counter
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Function) {
  return {
    increment: () => dispatch(increment()),
    decrement: () => dispatch(decrement())
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter)
```

Class that use the counter

```js
// @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Counter} from './counter';

class MainCounter extends Component
{

 render ()
 {
  return (
   <div>
    <Counter />
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, yes that does make the errors show up but that's because I am no longer getting any props at all passed into the component since you're not using the `connect` version, which isn't really what i want to do. I guess my main question is why doesn't flow make sure its okay when I use the `connect` version?

Comment: I don't know Redux. Maybe yo can try this: const connector: Connector<Props, any> = connect((state, ownProps: Props)=>({}));
export default connector(Counter);